# R: How to install package tiff on Mac OS X Mavericks?

Tags: r, macos, tiff

I'd like to install package tiff from rforge (http://www.rforge.net/tiff/index.html) on Mac OS X Mavericks.

R-Version is

```
    > version
                   _                           
    platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0   
    arch           x86_64                      
    os             darwin13.1.0                
    system         x86_64, darwin13.1.0        
    status                                     
    major          3                           
    minor          1.0                         
    year           2014                        
    month          04                          
    day            10                          
    svn rev        65387                       
    language       R                           
    version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
    nickname       Spring Dance
```

Trying to install it I get the following error:

```
    > install.packages("tiff","http://rforge.net/",type="source")
    Warning in install.packages :
      'lib = "http://rforge.net/"' is not writable
    Would you like to use a personal library instead?  (y/n) y
    versuche URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tiff_0.1-5.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 28925 bytes (28 Kb)
    URL geöffnet
    ==================================================
    downloaded 28 Kb

    * installing *source* package ‘tiff’ ...
    ** Paket ‘tiff’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
    ** libs
    clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c common.c -o common.o
    In file included from common.c:1:
    ./common.h:5:10: fatal error: 'tiff.h' file not found
    #include <tiff.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    make: *** [common.o] Error 1
    ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tiff’
    * removing ‘/Users/stingl/Library/R/3.1/library/tiff’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘tiff’ had non-zero exit status

    The downloaded source packages are in
      ‘/private/var/folders/8_/1kgvxblj3ss4pzmsgx3pkysc0000gn/T/RtmpYmsCmF/downloaded_packages’
```

Any ideas?

Comment: According to the error message (fatal error: 'tiff.h' file not found), you need headers for the tiff library.

Comment: You need to specify `repos=` since the rforge address is in the place where `lib` is expected to be. But I doubt that is the cause for the failure.

Comment: Simple answer: don't even try.  Get the CRAN `rtiff` package instead. It works just fine.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft According to cran this package isn't availible for Mavericks as binary. Trying to compile it I get the message that libtiff is missing.

Comment: Aha :-( . I've stuck w/ SnowLeopard so I tend to forget that Simon's madly trying to figure out how to get every package to work on 3 incompatible OS X versions.

Comment: You need `libtiff` in order to compile `tiff` to be included in `R`.  Check out: http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/libtiff/ .  I did this and I managed to get `tiff` to compile under Mavericks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got [macports](http://www.macports.org/) or [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed, you should use them to install libtiff.

Here's what you need to run to install libtiff using homebrew:

```
brew install libtiff
```

After this is done, you can install the tiff package in R:

```
install.packages("tiff", type="source")
```

Cheers,

George